# Différence entre avoir et prendre avec voudrais

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

Can I use these sentences interchangeably. Does both of them mean the same thing?

```
je voudrais prendre un café

je voudrais avoir un café.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je suis dehors et je dis à mon ami :

> Je voudrais prendre un café

Je suis à la table d’un café, je dis au serveur :

> S’il vous plaît, je voudrais avoir un café.

Au bar on peut dire aussi :

> S’il vous plaît,  servez-moi un café.

Il y a bien d’autres formules ; s’il s’agit de se faire servir un café dans une brasserie, vous serez de toutes façons servi, quelle que soit la phrase mentionnée dans votre question.

Comment: Cela rend plus facile.Parfait merci!

Answer (score 1):

je voudrais prendre un café 
=>cela veux dire que je veux boire un café (utilisation ou consommation de l'objet)

je voudrais avoir un café
=>cela veux dire que je veux avoir un café physiquement (possession de l'objet)

Comment: Familièrement, on peut aussi « *avoir un café* derrière la cravate » quand on a *pris* (et donc bu) *un café*.